# Does newSingleThreadExecutor return an ExecutorService wrapped by unconfigurableExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading *Java Concurrency in Practice*, and there's something puzzled me:

> Executors includes a factory method, ***unconfigurableExecutorService***, which takes an existing ExecutorService and wraps it with one exposing only the methods of ExecutorService so it cannot be further configured. Unlike the pooled implementations, ***newSingleThreadExecutor* returns an ExecutorService wrapped in this manner**, rather than a raw ThreadPoolExecutor.

I've read the source code of ***newSingleThreadExecutor***, but just couldn't find how it's wrapped by ***unconfigurableExecutorService***?

Answer (score 2):

[`unconfigurableExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#unconfigurableExecutorService-java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService-) is a **method**.

The value returned by `newSingleThreadExecutor` is not wrapped by `unconfigurableExecutorService`, but something similar. Its [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--) states

> Unlike the otherwise equivalent `newFixedThreadPool(1)` **the returned
>   executor is guaranteed not to be reconfigurable to use additional
>   threads.**

---

This is simply done with proper encapsulation. `newFixedThreadPool` returns a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, a class that implements `ExecutorService`. You could cast the result and use its methods

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
```

You can't do that with the result of `newSingleThreadExecutor`, because it doesn't return a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, it returns some other class that implements `ExecutorService`.